# What are some ways to store level data in a game like Gunpoint?

Tags: 2d, data-structure, level-design

Gunpoint is a 2D stealth game available [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/206190/). I was wondering how you might go about storing level data for a game like this. I'm mostly concerned about how the collision detection is saved. There are several types of things which need to be stored; solid objects (walls, floors/roofs), breakable objects (glass), and editable objects (doors, light switches). A tile based approach may work, but I think that getting small details like light switches in there would get hairy quick.

[image: gunpoint screenshot]
<sub>(source: [steamstatic.com](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/206190/ss_74d9eee2fe86c3d269940349d767509706a52742.1920x1080.jpg?t=1379445757))</sub>

Comment: Why does it need to be tile-based? It could store the locations of every object's x/y coordinates as-is.

Comment: @congusbongus I was actually thinking that a tile-based approach would not be ideal. If you were to store each object's x & y coordinate, how would you save/load maps? Just by hardcoding each individual floor and wall and light bulb into place? Seems a bit tedious to me..

Comment: Pretty broad. What have you tried? Exactly what problem did you come up with that you're trying to solve?

Comment: tangent: I'd never heard of this game before but it looks almost identical to a game from the Zero Punctuation guy, hm http://www.escapistmagazine.com/content/games/yahtzee/artoftheft

Comment: @jhocking the description at your link sounds very unlike the gameplay of gunpoint.  Visual style is close, though.

Comment: Probably the same way as in any other game.

Comment: If you're curious as to how it was done in this game, I suggest you take a look at some dev blogs/ videos and talks by tom francis. He made the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are approaching this from the wrong angle completely.

There are a few ways around this but first you need to decide if your tiles and your collision can have differing states. Eg: can a particular wall be passed through on one level/location and not in another. If so we can use method 1.

Firstly you need to index your tiles regardless of which method you use eg. wall_tile_01 may be an image but you need to know it by number.

```
empty_space = 0
wall_tile_01 = 1
wall_tile_02 = 2
etc
```

This makes things easier to track and manage machine/code side. so by assigning a list of id's you can now divide your level up into 2D arrays filled with bytes or shorts. (it is unlikely you will have more than 65,535 unique tile images)

The best way I found is to divide your world into a series of grids firstly your tile grid and secondly your region grid. Each region has a 2d index like (0,0) or (0,1) or (1,0) etc
Each index refers to a tile grid.

A tile grid would have to be a fixed size eg: 10 tiles by 10 tiles so 10x10 would give you 100 tiles per region.

If depth is needed you can have each region refer to multiple layers so you may have a background layer, middle-ground layer and a foreground layer.

in method 1)

We are assuming that the tiles have no direct relationship to collision so an additional layer would be added for collision. If you have different collision shapes then use the indexing method on collider shapes (none = 0, box = 1, slope_01 = 2, blah blah blah)

now you can store each your tile layers and collision layers as .bmp or .png 10px*10px images for each region and I'll explain how this works at the bottom. examples of this would be images with names like

```
level_01_BG_0-0.bmp
level_01_MG_0-0.bmp
level_01_FG_0-0.bmp
level_01_collision_0-0.bmp

level_01_BG_0-1.bmp
level_01_MG_0-1.bmp
level_01_FG_0-1.bmp
level_01_collision_0-1.bmp
```

For method 2)

We are assuming that tiles on a particular layer have a direct relationship to collision.

That is we assume that any tile that isn't a) assigned index 0 b) using another non collidable index you defined, on a particular layer is collidable which is much easier and allows you to use pixel perfect collision on that layer and that layer only.
Now saving the levels and collision are the same as above but would look a bit more like this.

```
level_01_BG_0-0.bmp
level_01_MG-collision_0-0.bmp
level_01_FG_0-0.bmp

level_01_BG_0-1.bmp
level_01_MG_collision_0-1.bmp
level_01_FG_0-1.bmp
```

Now for the bit about saving these levels and how it works.
Remember the indexing I spoke about? That also serves a purpose for saving. By converting your tile arrays to images you can then load the images as tile arrays. If you have less than 255 tiles you can do a simple byte array which can be directly translated to an image channel so if a pixel is empty at index 0,0 of your tile array the the top left pixel of the image you create is RGB value 0,0,0 and if it is wall_tile_01 then the RGB value is 0,0,1.

now if you have more that 255 unique tiles you need to use more color channels and a short array. You also need to translate your shorts into groups of bytes.
Essentially though if index 0,0 has the tile value 256 then the RBG value is 0,1,0
and if it is 257 then the RBG vaule is 0,1,1.

```
258 = 0,1,2
259 = 0,1,3
260 = 0,1,4
```

this kind of conversion is just a matter of maths though.

Hope this helps.

Note: You should use unsigned bytes or shorts for your tile arrays as this makes managing the data easier and makes conversion to image easier.

Comment: So in order to use bitmaps to save / load levels, would I need to edit the levels in a program like paint, editing each individual pixel? Are there any programs you know of which will assist in this process? I could probably make a custom level editor, but that would delay the project I'm working on currently by quite a while.

Comment: making a level editor would probably be faster than using paint. but yes you could use paint. simply though if you can write a program to read and write the level data you are 90% of the way there to making a level editor. :)

Answer (score 2):

For a game *like* this, options are nearly limitless, and the full process of inventing such a system would be beyond the scope of this site's Q&A format.

However, Gunpoint in particular [was made with GameMaker (see the "engine" info detail)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpoint_%28video_game%29), an engine which handles all those details for you.  The level data structures, the collision detection, the collision response, and everything else, was all in-engine features.

So perhaps that is your concise answer.  How do you make a game like this that does all these things?  Use an existing engine.